# How can I call a table class in selenium and phpunit

Tags: class, selenium, phpunit

How can I use `click()` function on a class of a table in selenium and phpunit.

```
table id="accType1" class="accType tooltip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in xpath

```
table[class=whatever]
```